# Is there a verb that means "talk a lot" but not necessarily annoyingly?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I'm looking for a verb that expresses the action of talking a lot or giving a lot of information.

I found the verb "to babble" for example, but I think it also means being a bit boring, annoying which is not necessarily true in my case.

**Edit**
I chose initially not to explain the usage because I thought nobody would take it seriously. But to make this question clearer, let's do it anyway.

First, I'm curious if there is such a verb. :)
Second, I usually try to use expressive words and verbs in my programs, but also try to avoid too long notations, hence I'm looking for a simple verb, not a "convoluted" expression.

Comment: Not a verb, but the person you are describing is a "good conversationalist".

Comment: There's not enough detail, could you please write a sentence where this verb would be used. And can you tell us which words you discarded when you searched [*babble* in a thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/babble).

Comment: Again, not verbs but such a person may be considered *loquacious* or *garrulous*.

Comment: in a program, I want to name a function that sends more information than usual.

Comment: Mari-Lou A Nice guess ^^. I simply put Talk I think. But I usually cross multiple words and read definitions to make sure I'm not taking a completely out of place one. There are lots of them on Thesaurus sadly.

Comment: It might get a chuckle the first time, but *gush* seems to hit all the bases. "2
:  to say or write effusively" [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gush)

Answer (score 2):

The first one that comes to mind is "gab." As in kissing the Blarney stone gives you the gift of "gab."  Or "he can't stop gabbing like a teenaged girl."

Comment: Well thank you for this quick answer :). I'll wait a bit maybe there will be more answers.

Comment: Gab for me at least has the negative connotation of being empty of real content.

Comment: @MAA Agree. Just be careful how you use it. The "gift of gab" can be derisive and can also leave a taste of empty content. So be careful there. Loquacious is a good option but is an adjective. You can use Loquaciously, which is an adverb. I would go with "loquaciously talking...." or "volubly speaking...." or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

There is also chattering (to chatter) (or the cliché "chattering like a magpie"), talking volubly, and, as a more "passive" construction, just being loquacious.

Comment: Hi Maria. Your answer would be improved by adding references.

Comment: +1 "loquacious" is the first word that came to mind for me - which of course isn't a verb, but I think best communicates the idea.

Comment: Except I clearly asked for a verb :)

Answer (score -1):

How about waffling or waffled.

Ex. The teacher is waffling on about English Grammar again.

Ex. He waffled on and on  about the price of oranges.

I will stop now before I'm accused of waffling too much.

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster, [waffle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waffle) means "to talk or write foolishly." I'd consider that "annoyingly."

Comment: Waffling means long winded but whether it is foolish or annoying is purely subjective.  I can listen to someone waffling, but I might find them amusing or even interesting.

Comment: do you have a dictionary that supports this?

Answer (score -1):

verbose, loquacious

both words mean to talk a great deal, and have a slightly negative connotation

Comment: These words are related, but the OP asked for a verb; these are adjectives.

Answer (score -1):

A person who is **articulate** talks fluently and communicates information.

See http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/articulate%20speech.

Most descriptions of people who talk a lot, like chatty, garrulous, etc., have a slightly negative connotation of talking too much and not listening enough.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I wondered again how I would say it in my mother language. Turns out there's a word that spells the same in English:

So one  could use **to detail**.